# Getting only Wednesday and Thursday from dates in php

Tags: php, date, filter, days

I have run into a bit of a rut... I have individual dates saved in my database. I am outputting them for editing and I need to be able to only select an individual day (ex. Wednesday) or various days (ex. Thursdays and Fridays) and filter them in my output. I have never done this before and have no idea how to do it. I am outputting the dates in a simple while loop from the DB:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$getRates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rates WHERE hotel_id = '$hotelId' AND contract_id = '$contractId' AND room_id='$roomId' AND DATE(booking_date) >= '$today'") or die(mysql_error());
while($room = mysql_fetch_array($getRates)){
    $bdat = $room['booking_date'];
    $bdate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($bdat));
    echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='date' value='$bdate' checked='checked' /></td>";
    echo "<td>$bdate</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }}
```

And this is my filter:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="Monday" />Lunes
<input type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked" name="Tuesday" />Martes
<input type="checkbox" value="3" checked="checked" name="Wednesday" />Miercoles
<input type="checkbox" value="4" checked="checked" name="Thursday"/>Jueves
<input type="checkbox" value="5" checked="checked" name="Friday"/>Viernes
<input type="checkbox" value="6" checked="checked" name="Saturday"/>Sabado
<input type="checkbox" value="7" checked="checked" name="Sunday"/>Domingo
<input type="submit" name="filter" value="Filtar Dias" />
```

Any help on this subject would be soooooo greatly appreciated. I really have no idea how to go about doing this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It might be because it is really late for me but can you explain what is the problem? Do you want to have all the dates listed but have checked only these that are present in the database or there is something else?

Comment: @Grzegorz I concur, explain what you're trying to do ideally.

Comment: Slightly off topic but if you are writing MySQL queries this way I recommend using some kind of parameterisation   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#69365
this can save you injection issues and make your code easier to maintain also see http://www.sitepoint.com/parameterised-sql-queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to use the dayname function:

SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE DAYNAME(yourdatecolumn) = 'Tuesday';

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DAYOFWEEK(some_event_date) = 7;
```

Comment: nop... this does not work at all :(.. but thank you for trying